# How to tell if the action was invoked from Generic Inquiry Mass Action?

Tags: acumatica

I have a generic inquiry than can execute mass actions. This particular action then executes a redirect and pops up another screen. I can modify the action delegate and stop it from redirecting. But only if it's called from Generic Inquiry Mass Action. Is there a flag in the graph like IsMassProcess or IsImport etc ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There are flags IsExport, IsImport, IsContractBasedAPI and plenty of other IsXXXXX. Regarding IsMassAction in case of non Generic inquiry Acumatica team passes bool variable isMassAction in processing method. Regarding IsMassAction I suppose we can ask Acumatica team to add that field at feedback.acumatica.com

Comment: I did look at all the IsXXXX flags and they're all False. So I suspect there isn't one yet for telling it's coming from Mass Action. So at this point I'm just curious if there's any tell tale sign if the screen itself was invoked from GI for example.